# Task List - Project Professional / Standard

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, task-list, ms-project, office-2016

We are facing the following issue:

We have a SharePoint 2013 farm and users have Office Pro Plus 2016 as well as Project Standard 2016 installed (both 32bit).

When opening a task list in SharePoint and clicking "Open with Project" we get the following error message:

[image]

Unfortunately I do not have access to Project Professional 2016 at this point so i can't check if that would work.

We tried setting the IE's compatibility mode to v9 (as suggested on some blogs) and lower - to no avail.

We also checked with [KB4022217](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022217/july-3-2018-update-for-project-2016-kb4022217) but we already had that installed.

**My question:** Do we need Project Professional 2016 to open task lists in project or are we missing a feature / setting here to make it work with the Standard edition?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use "Open with Project", you need to have **Project Professional** installed on your computer for that to work.

Two articles for your reference:
[How to Sync MS Project with SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/sync-ms-project-with-sharepoint/)
[Sync with a SharePoint tasks list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sync-with-a-sharepoint-tasks-list-fb956d2c-723d-4d5a-b7e5-710ef82aa27a#ID0EAABAAA=Office_2013_-_Office_365)